# Session Register not working

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a problem with registering sessions on my websites login script:I tried the following script,but it keeps redirecting to the main login page, I suspect that the script is not  registering the session.please help me.
**here is script**:

***checklogin.php***

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","p11","daot");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM registration WHERE 
Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'");


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysqli_num_rows($sql);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_start();
$_SESSION["myusername"];
$_SESSION["mypassword"];
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

**login_success.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
    {
   header('Location:login.php');
    }
    ?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As always: `session_start();` must go at the top of the page.

Comment: I make it at the top,but nothing is changed.

Comment: @@john Conde hope.... not compulsory to place as top/first  ,,, session must be start before going to be manipulate

Answer (score 1):

replace the checking.php with this and try it pls :

```
<?php
session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","p11","daot");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM registration WHERE 
Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'");


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysqli_num_rows($sql);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

$_SESSION["myusername"] = $mypassword;
$_SESSION["mypassword"] = $mypassword;
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your session_start() to the top of the page. 
Also, you are not assigning any value to 
$_SESSION["myusername"]; or $_SESSION["mypassword"];
Set those values after you initialize $myusername and $mypassword.

```
$_SESSION["myusername"] = $myusername;
$_SESSION["mypassword"] =  $mypassword;
```

Comment: ik , i was did to notice no more ,i was going to cancel it . but seem i can cancel it . he have to edit so i can cancel it .

Comment: @user1844933 but he said some thing not correct . you can't set the values to $_SESSION after initialize  $myusername and $mypassword. you have to set them after you get the if($count==1) so you login if the credentials are correct .